# Rendering a select tag on Click - REACT JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to render a select tag whenever a div/text was click.

I am not sure where and how to render it exactly.

So I created a handle function that will set a variable isItClick to true to render the select statement:

```
   _handleClickSelect(){
    isItClick = true;
    console.log('here is the select tag')
  }
```

And then passed it along with my component:

```
 <ItemList _handleClick={this.props._handleClick} />
```

then on my div I tried to execute it but this did not work of course:

```
render() {
const selectList(){
  var isItClick = false;

  if(isItClick === true){
    <div className="sss-data" onClick={this.props._handleClickSelect}>
       <select>
      <option value="1">Item 1</option>
      <option value="2">Item 2</option>
      <option value="3">Item 3</option>
    </select>
    </div>

  } else {
     <div className="ss" onClick={this.props._handleClickSelect}>TEXT</div>
  }
}
return (
  <div className="ss-row"
    {selectList}
  </div>
);
```

}

Any idea how can I render/change the text to a select tag after the TEXT was click and then put it back after selecting an item? Sorry newbie here. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use a constructor states?

Comment: Can you show me a demo on how to do that? Sorry I am just testing out and looking for ways to render it properly.

Comment: do i need to create a state?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a constructor states instead of creating a variable?

Document from [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Here's an example

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {show: false};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        {this.state.show ? 
            <div className="sss-data" onClick={this.props._handleClickSelect}>
              <select>
                <option value="1">Item 1</option>
                <option value="2">Item 2</option>
                <option value="3">Item 3</option>
              </select>
           </div>
     : <button onClick={()=> this.setState({ show: true })}>Show</button>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what I want, check again my codes at the top. And see what I mean. By default there is already a text in the div. So If I click on that text, it will transform the text to the select tag.

Answer (score 0):

Add a state to the component and do a conditional render. This will use the `renderText` if `showSelected` is not set, and use `renderSelected` if it is set.

The syntax for the conditional render is as follows: `{this.state.showSelected ? this.renderSelected() : this.renderText()}` which can be written as:

```js
if (this.state.showSelect) {
  return this.renderSelected();
} else {
  return this.renderText();
}
```

Or even more compact with the whole code included:

```js
    constructor() {
      this.state = { showSelected: false }
    }

    render() {
      return {this.state.showSelected ? this.renderSelected() : this.renderText()}
    }
    renderText = () => {
      return <div className="ss" onClick={this.handleTextClick}>TEXT</div>;
    }

    renderSelected = () => {
      return <div className="sss-data">
           <select>
              <option value="1">Item 1</option>
              <option value="2">Item 2</option>
              <option value="3">Item 3</option>
          </selected>
        </div>;
    }
    
    handleTextClick = () => {
      this.setState({showSelected: true});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you may use one stateful component and one stateless component or one stateful component. When state changed don't `setState` directly `true` it's opposite of current state `isItClick : !this.state.isItClick` you may try this..
 **stateful** `SelectComponent`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ItemList from './ItemList';

class SelectComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    isItClick: false
  }
  this._handleClickSelect = this._handleClickSelect.bind(this);
}

_handleClickSelect = (value) => {
  this.setState(() => ({
    isItClick : !this.state.isItClick
  }));
  if(typeof value !== 'object'){
    console.log(value);
  }
}
render() {
   return (
      <div>
        {this.state.isItClick
          ? <ItemList _handleClick={this._handleClickSelect}/>
          : <div className="ss" onClick={this._handleClickSelect}>TEXT</div>
        }

      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default SelectComponent;
```

And **stateless `ItemList` Component**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
const ItemList = (props) => {
return (
  <div className="sss-data">
    <select onChange={(e) => props._handleClick(e.target.value)}>
      <option value="1">Item 1</option>
      <option value="2">Item 2</option>
      <option value="3">Item 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  );
}
export default ItemList;
```